# R Identify Duplicate Columns as Groups

Tags: r

I have a dataframe but can't figure out how to group the duplicate columns based on their values.  How do I summarize these data so that I can identify the duplicate columns as 3 distinct groups as follows:
A & C,
B & D,
E,

```
A=c(1,0,1)
B=c(1,0,0)
C=c(1,0,1)
D=c(1,0,0)
E=c(0,0,0)

testframe = data.frame(A=A,B=B,C=C,D=D,E=E)

dupsremoved<-testframe[!duplicated(lapply(testframe, summary))]
```

Comment: Duplicates based on what? Their `summary` values?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want the output to look like? Not sure how you are defining your duplicates, and that will help.

Comment: Yes duplicates based on their values.  A & C are both 1,0,1 B & D are both 1,0,0

Answer (score 0):

Use t() twice and unique():

```
A=c(1,0,1)
B=c(1,0,0)
C=c(1,0,1)
D=c(1,0,0)
E=c(0,0,0)

testframe = data.frame(A=A,B=B,C=C,D=D,E=E)
testframe
#   A B C D E
# 1 1 1 1 1 0
# 2 0 0 0 0 0
# 3 1 0 1 0 0

# transpose
testframex <- t(testframe)
testframex

# remove duplicated rows
testframe1 <- unique(testframex)
testframe1

# transpose again
dupsremoved <- as.data.frame(t(testframe1))
dupsremoved

#   A B E
# 1 1 1 0
# 2 0 0 0
# 3 1 0 0
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I still don't know that A and C are in the same group and that B and D are in the same group.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Clunky but effective way to create strings (`sss`) from your columns and compare on that basis:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tibble)
> sss <- data.frame(apply(testframe,2,function(x) paste0(x,collapse=",")))
> names(sss) <- c("pattern")
> sss2 <- sss %>% rownames_to_column()
> lapply(unique(sss2$pattern), function(x) sss2$rowname[which(sss2$pattern==x)]) 
[[1]]
[1] "A" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "D"

[[3]]
[1] "E"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `%in%` function to check if the column(s) with identical values exists in the data.frame

```
df <- testframe # just to make a name shorter
df %in% df[1]   # df[1] is a data.frame with a single column (not a vector)

TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Thus now it's just a question of how to iterate over every column and how to replace logical values corresponding to the columns with its names.
I did it as follows to get the groups of column names with identical values:

```
unique(lapply(seq(df), function(x) names(df)[df %in% df[x]]))

[[1]]
[1] "A" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "D"

[[3]]
[1] "E"
```

#### Larger Datasets

Due to performance, it is worth encoding the columns with its values to hashes and only then does the comparison. Wrapped in a function for convenience:

```
library(digest)

colTwins <- function(df) {
        hash.v <- vapply(df, function(x) digest(x), character(1))
        unique(lapply(seq(df), function(z) names(df)[hash.v %in% hash.v[z]]))
}

colTwins(df = df)

[1] "A" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "D"

[[3]]
[1] "E"
```